# Python column with order number based on conditions

Tags: python

I have a table shown as below:

[image]

Customers are buying items in different dates. Each customer have a different number. Each item has a different ID.

I want to have an information in separate column for each ID is it first item for given customer or second or third etc.

I was trying:

```
df['item_order'] = np.where(df['Customer']==df['Customer'].shift(),
                       df.item_order.shift()+1, 0)
```

But there are only 0 for first and 1 for second, third etc.

Comment: You can find the rank of the rows by grouping the results on customer id and product id and order by date. Refer - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the below code using pandas

```
df[['ID','Customer','Date']].groupby(['ID','Customer']).agg('count')
```

Let me know if this is the output that you are expecting

Comment: Though not sure, I believe he's looking for `rank()`

Comment: Unfortunately i have only "1" values. I think It's because ID is unique. So ['ID','Customer'] will be also unique

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help for everybody, solution is rank method.

You can find below solution for my issue:
df['rank'] = df.sort_values('Customer').groupby('Customer').Date.rank(method='first')